# (Unity) Why is my C# Monobehaviour Script not beeing detected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey I've got this neat little unity script (C#) for handling the spawning of some game objects.
It works perfectly fine in the original project, but after I transfered it into a new project I suddenly
had this error:
No MonoBehavior scripts in the file, or their names do not match the file name.
Does anyone know where this error is coming from? Because I can't use the script this way.

Yes the class name and the file name do match.
Btw I'm posting this here because the Unity forum is broken af.
Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PrefabManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    ObjectPooler objectPooler;
    public GameManager gm;
    
    int rnd = 0;
    float difficulty = 1.5f;
    bool diffhelp = true;
    int duplicate;

    
    
    private void Start()
    {
        objectPooler = ObjectPooler.Instance;
        duplicate = rnd;
        
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        bool hardcore = gm.hardcore;
        switch (gm.score)
        {
            case 150:
                difficulty = 1.25f;
                break;
            case 300:
                difficulty = 1f;
                break;
            case 450:
                difficulty = 0.9f;
                break;
            case 600:
                difficulty = 0.8f;
                break;
            case 750:
                difficulty = 0.7f;
                break;
            case 900:
                difficulty = 0.6f;
                break;
        }
        if (diffhelp)
        {
            if (hardcore == false)
            {
                Invoke("spawn", difficulty);
                diffhelp = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Invoke("spawn", 0.6f);
                diffhelp = false;
            }
            
        }

    }

    private void spawn()
    {
        while (duplicate == rnd)
        {
            rnd = Random.Range(0, 7);
        }
        duplicate = rnd;
        diffhelp = true;
        objectPooler.SpawnFromPool(rnd.ToString(), new Vector3(0,1,100), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: The file is named `PrefabManager.cs`? Where is it in your project in relation to the `Assets` directory?

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes the file name is PrefabManager.cs . It is located in Assets\Scripts

Comment: I'd apply the usual troubleshooting steps. Check again, outside Unity to make sure the name is right. Right click it and reimport. Make a different script and see if that works, etc.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I already did all of that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLUTION FOUND:
It appears to be that the error mentioned in my question not only gets triggered if there is any sort of error in the script. I didn't know about that however. I fixed it now and it's working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you don't have this:

[image]

This should say `Assembly C-Sharp`, you can do this by opening the script from the `.sln` (the solution file of the project)

If you need more information of how to this you can [look here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bUD4s4sXSeE)